# string constant and JSON processing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

so I have a string constant

```
MyString.START = 'start';
```

I have a JSON that I need to parse, let call it input

I want to be able to say `input[MyString.START]`.

what does the syntax look like for this?

Comment: Exactly like this. `input[MyString.START]`. Assuming that `input` is actually the parsed data, not JSON. If that doesn't work for you, you have to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more details to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var MyString = {};
MyString.START = 'start';

var json = '{"start": 1,"prop2": 2}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj[MyString.START]); // prints 1
```

Comment: I would just add a property check too.  if(obj && obj.hasOwnProperty(MyString.START))
    console.log(obj[MyString.START]);

Comment: Just remember that `var MyString.START` isn't valid -- I've fixed that for you.

Comment: @Qantas Yeah, I saw that. Stupid typo. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we'd just access the object like this:

```
input.start
```

However, sometimes we want to access the property name that's stored in a variable.  We use bracket notation to do that:

```
input[MyString.START]
```

Read more about interacting with object properties at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)